# Is it possible to drill down to an element with page object

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

I'm trying to use Cheezy's page-object gem for everything in order to be consistent. However I haven't been able to find how to drill down to an element like this. The situation here is that there would be more than one link with all the same tags so you have to drill down from something identifiable.

```
@browser.p(:text => /#{app_name}/i).link(:text => 'Add').click
```

The code I'm looking for would be something like this to click on a link located inside of a paragraph but it doesn't work.

```
p(:pgraph, id: => 'some-pgraph')
link(:lnk, text: => 'add')    

self.pgraph.lnk
```

Is there a way to do this with page object?

Thanks,
Adam

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use blocks to define accessors with more complicated locating strategies.

If you want to also keep a reference to the paragraph:

```
p(:pgraph, id: 'some-pgraph')
link(:lnk){ pgraph_element.link_element(text: 'add') }
```

Or if you do not need the paragraph for other things, you might do:

```
link(:lnk){ paragraph_element(id: 'some-pgraph').link_element(text: 'add') }
```

Basically you can use a block with [nested elements](http://rubydoc.info/github/cheezy/page-object/master/PageObject/NestedElements), to define accessors similar to how you would in Watir.

Note that if you want to specify the id dynamically at run time, you can always define a method to click the link instead of using the accessors:

```
def click_link_in(paragraph_id)
  paragraph_element(id: paragraph).link_element(text: 'add').click
end
```

Comment: You know what would be nice is if you could use regex in the declaration for use later when dealing with dynamic content or maybe a scenario outline where you want to do the same element type over and over with different names. ```link(:lnk){ paragraph_element(id: #{variable_name}).link_element(text: 'add') }```

Comment: You can always just create a regular method for those situations - see example in updated answer.

Comment: Of course but part of what's great about page object is all of the generated methods that you don't have to make manually. It would be great if you could declare a regex element and have page object generate methods that include passing a variable. Probably asking way too much but it sure would be neat!